# How to make an unumbered lemma and sublemma

Tags: numbering, theorems

I am trying to define an unumbered lemma and sublemma like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{lemma*}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{sublemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem*{sublemma*}{Lemma}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{1}
\begin{lemma*}
text
\end{lemma*}
\end{document}
```

But when I do this I get an error saying "Missing \begin{document" for the line where I defined lemma* and sublemma*. Why is it doing this for only those and not the other definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unnumbered theorem environment does not need a dependent counter, so drop those.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{lemma*}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{sublemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem*{sublemma*}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem*}
An unnumbered theorem.
\end{theorem*}

\begin{lemma}
A lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma*}
An unnumbered lemma.
\end{lemma*}

\begin{sublemma}
A sublemma.
\end{sublemma}

\begin{sublemma*}
An unnumbered sublemma.
\end{sublemma*}

\end{document}
```